# Migrationによる、Realmモデル構造の追加と削除

Tags: swift, realm

今あるrealmデータを保持したまま、マイグレーションでモデルの構造を変更したいのですが、方法がわかりません。

具体的には、Realmデータクラスの`ThreadData`内にある `dynamic var aaaaa = ""`を構造から削除し、新たに`dynamic var bbbbb = ""`を追加したいです。
そこで、下記の通り記述しましたが、エラー内容にあるように、`aaaaa`は削除できておらず、`bbbbb`は追加できていないようです。
さらに、別のrealmを利用している他のクラスの`let realm = try! Realm()`でEXC_BAD_INSTRUCTIONエラーとなります。

なお、今あるdefalut.realmを削除して再度生成した場合は、これらの構造変更は反映されています。

```
fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=10 "Migration is required due to the following errors:
- Property 'aaaaa' is missing from latest object model.
- Property 'bbbbb' has been added to latest object model." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Migration is required due to the following errors:
- Property 'aaaaa' is missing from latest object model.
- Property 'bbbbb' has been added to latest object model., Error Code=10}: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-703.0.18.8/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 54
```

`ThreadData`

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift
class ThreadData: Object {
    //dynamic var aaaaa = ""
    dynamic var bbbbb = ""
}
```

`AppDelegate`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //        UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)


    let migrationBlock: MigrationBlock = { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
            migration.enumerate(TeamData.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
                }
            }
        }
        if oldSchemaVersion < 3 {
            migration.enumerate(ThreadData.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                newObject!["bbbbb"] as! String
                let weaponID = oldObject!["aaaaa"] as! String


            }
        }
        print("Migration complete.")
    }

    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: 4, migrationBlock: migrationBlock)
    return true
}
```

`NoUserView`

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class NoUserView: UIView, UITextViewDelegate, PlacePickerViewDelegate {

    var finishUserRegisterButton : UIButton = UIButton()

//中略

    let realm = try! Realm()//こちらでエラーが発生します。
    let user = PersonalData()



    override init(frame:CGRect) {
        super.init(frame:frame)
        //setupCustomView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        //setupCustomView()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

エラーの内容はプロパティが追加・削除できていないのではありません。モデルの定義が変更されていて既存のデータファイルと合っていないので、マイグレーションが必要、というエラーです。つまり、モデルは変更されていますが、マイグレーションが正しく行われていません。

Realmのマイグレーションは

1. スキーマバージョンを上げることでデータ構造が変わったことをRealmに通知し、
2. 必要に応じて過去のデータ構造から新しいデータ構造にデータを移行

という２つの処理があります。データを移行が必要ない（新しく増えたプロパティは空でいい）場合は「2」は必要ありません。（スキーマバージョンを上げるだけでマイグレーションブロックは書かなくて良い）

さて、書かれているエラーが出ているということは、「１」の手順で、より大きいスキーマバージョンが正しく設定されてないということになります。

おそらく原因は、`schemaVersion`を`4`にしていますが、数え間違えていてすでにファイルのスキーマバージョンは`4`なのだと思います。`schemaVersion`を`5`以上にしてみてください。

または、`NoUserView`がStoryboardで使われている場合、`application(application:,didFinishL‌​aunchingWithOptions:)`が呼ばれるより前にStoryboardによってメンバ変数の`let realm = try! Realm()`が呼ばれてしまうので、マイグレーションの設定がされる前にRealmが作られてしまいます。

このように、Storyboardで使われるビューのメンバ‌​変数でRealmを初期化している場合、その部分を`lazy var realm = try! Realm()`にしてください。そうすることで、`realm`変数が最初に使われるときまで初期化を遅らせることができます。

Comment: migration内容を'oldSchemaVersion < 20'とし、'Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: 21, migrationBlock: migrationBlock)'としましたが、引き続きエラーが出る状況です。追加、削除の記述自体は問題なさそうでしょうか？

Comment: マイグレーションはRealmを開く際に行われるのでRealmのインスタンスを作成している部分のコードを載せていただけますか？別の設定オブジェクトを渡したりしてませんか？またデフォルトの設定を他のところで書き換えたりしてませんか？

Comment: 様々なswiftファイルでインスタンスを生成していますが、実際にエラーが出ている部分を追加で載せました。NoUserVIewというものがそれにあたります。また、デフォルト設定を他のところで書き換えていないかということですが、具体的にはRealm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = を上記部分で設定していないかということで認識はあっていますでしょうか。プロジェクト全体で検索しましたが、appdelegateの上記部分以外でこの記述があったのは、Migration.swiftだけでした

Comment: @Taka.H おそらく、`NoUserView`はStoryboardで使われてないですか？その場合、`application(application:,didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`が呼ばれるより前にStoryboardによってメンバ変数の`let realm = try! Realm()`が呼ばれてしまうので、マイグレーションの設定がされる前にRealmが作られてしまいます。このように、Storyboardで使われるビューのメンバ変数でRealmを初期化している場合、その部分を`lazy var realm = try! Realm()`にしてください。そうすることで、`realm`変数が最初に使われるときまで初期化を遅らせることができます。

Comment: おそらく上記で合ってると思います。回答にも同じ内容を追記しました。

Comment: storyboardの方が、先に呼ばれるんですね。storyboardで使われてはいないように見えましたが、 `lazy var realm = try! Realm()`としたところ、無事migrationできました。思ってもみないところで、呼んでしまっていたのかもしれません。ありがとうございました。